# framework version upgrade causing problem to my project

Tags: react-native, frameworks, simctl

I was building a react native project and got an upgrade message when I run "yarn run ios":

simctl[5640:1381079] CoreSimulator detected version change. Framework version (857.14) does not match existing job version (857.13). Attempting to remove the stale service in order to add the expected version. error Could not get the simulator list from Xcode. Please open Xcode and try running project directly from there to resolve the remaining issues. SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0、

However, after this upgrade, there is something wrong with my project. Any suggestion how to back to the old version?

I tried to use other version of ios simulator and tried to clean the xcode build, but its not help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue. The trick was

1. Quit all iOS simulators
2. Let Xcode install the newest iOS simulators
3. Run the project from the Xcode workspace.

After that I was able to start the simulator again from `npx react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone 14'` or `yarn run iOS`

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is on a Windows PC...I upgraded Xcode on my Mac and restarted Visual studios.

Once I paired to the Mac the issue was resolved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).